# How to query a table with a Where clause that loops through a different table?

Tags: teradata, where-clause, teradata-sql-assistant

I have 2 tables in my database

Table 1

```
 DC     Item     Day
6006    123      May 1
6006    123      May 2
7036    456      May 6
```

Table 2

```
 DC     Item      Day    ShippedCases    Label Type
6006    123      May 1       100             A
6006    123      May 2       200             A
6006    123      May 2       500             B 
7036    456      May 2       300             B
7036    456      May 6       400             A
```

Table 1 has all the unique records that I am interested in but it doesnt contain ShippedCases or Label Type. How can i write a query to select all the records from Table 2 that match the records in Table 1?

In this case I want to select the DC, Item, Day fields in Table 2 that Match Table 1 and sum the Shipped Cases where Label Type = A.

Result View

```
DC       Item   Day     Shipped Cases    Label Type
6006     123    May 1        100              A
6006     123    May 2        200              A 
7036     456    May 6        400              A
```

I think this is a simple Select statement but I am not where how to setup my where clause with my first 3 parameters being the Table 1 fields and a 4th parameter of Table 2 Label Type = A.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use an INNER JOIN here and aggregation with `SUM()` and a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT
    table1.DC,
    table1.Item,
    table1.Day,
    Sum(table2.ShippedCases) as ShippedCases,
    Table2.LabelType
FROM
    Table1
    INNER JOIN Table2 
        ON Table1.DC = Table2.DC
            AND Table1.Item = Table2.Item
            AND Table1.Day = Table2.Day
WHERE
    Table2.LabelType = 'A'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,5
```

If you have items in Table1 that don't appear in Table2, then you'll want to convert this to a LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT
    table1.DC,
    table1.Item,
    table1.Day,
    Sum(table2.ShippedCases) as ShippedCases,
    Table2.LabelType
FROM
    Table1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 
        ON Table1.DC = Table2.DC
            AND Table1.Item = Table2.Item
            AND Table1.Day = Table2.Day
            AND Table2.LabelType = 'A'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,5
```

Notice that we move the WHERE clause up into the ON clause of the LEFT OUTER JOIN to insure that only items in Table2 are restricted for that LabelType. In other words, Teradata will filter Table2 BEFORE joining to Table1. BEcause it's a LEFT OUTER JOIN you will get ALL records from Table1, and then only those from Table2 that pass the filter and match the ON conditions.

Comment: Of course, using the example data, the same result will be returned without aggregation. And if the Inner join provides the correct solution, there's no need for a join, you can simply aggregate table2 :-)